# UIMenuBuilder menu bar vs. context menu

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uimenubuilder

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimenubuilder) says, "To add and remove menus from the menu bar using the main menu system, override buildMenu(with:) in your app delegate. To build a context menu using the context system, override the method in your view controller."

However, I'm not seeing this behavior. All my menu code to build menus is in app delegate. I have multiple instances where I use `insertSibling()` and only one case where I build a menu from scratch:

```
        let zoomInCommand = UIKeyCommand(title: NSLocalizedString("Zoom In", comment: ""),
                                         image: nil,
                                         action: #selector(ViewController.zoomIn),
                                         input: "+",
                                         modifierFlags: .command)
        let zoomOutCommand = UIKeyCommand(title: NSLocalizedString("Zoom Out", comment: ""),
                                          image: nil,
                                          action: #selector(ViewController.zoomOut),
                                          input: "-",
                                          modifierFlags: .command)
        let zoomCancelCommand = UIKeyCommand(title: NSLocalizedString("Reset Zoom", comment: ""),
                                          image: nil,
                                          action: #selector(ViewController.zoomCancel),
                                          input: "0",
                                          modifierFlags: .command)
        let zoomMenu = UIMenu(title:"Zoom", identifier: UIMenu.Identifier("Zoom"), options:.displayInline ,children: [zoomInCommand,zoomOutCommand,zoomCancelCommand])
        builder.insertChild(zoomMenu, atEndOfMenu: .view)
```

Note: this zoomMenu is also built in the app delegate just like the other items. Here is an example of the `insertSibling()` function I mentioned.

```
        let saveProjectCommand = UIKeyCommand(title: NSLocalizedString("Save Project", comment: ""),
                                         image: nil,
                                         action: #selector(ViewController.saveProjectAndShowActivityIndicator),
                                         input: "p",
                                         modifierFlags: .command)
        let saveImageCommand = UIKeyCommand(title: NSLocalizedString("Save Image", comment: ""),
                                         image: nil,
                                         action: #selector(ViewController.saveImageAction),
                                         input: "i",
                                         modifierFlags: .command)
        let saveSVGCommand = UIKeyCommand(title: NSLocalizedString("Save SVG File", comment: ""),
                                         image: nil,
                                         action: #selector(ViewController.saveSVG),
                                         input: "g",
                                         modifierFlags: .command)
        let saveMenu = UIMenu(title:"Save",identifier: UIMenu.Identifier(rawValue: "Save"),children: [saveProjectCommand,saveSVGCommand,saveImageCommand])
        builder.insertSibling(saveMenu, beforeMenu: .close)
```

In my view controller, I use the `validate` function. The only items that show up there are the three zoom functions. Additionally, when running the app, if I long-press the COMMAND button, I get what appears to be a context menu with the zoom functions.
[image]
Given the documentation, since I defined that zoom function in app delegate, it should not appear here in the view controller, but it does. Also, if the zoom menu appears, why doesn't the save menu appear?

Answer (score 0):

The docs are a bit confusing here, because it seems that `buildMenuWithBuilder` is called on the app delegate for *all* menus. So it's triggered not just when building the system menu, but context menus as well. Typically the context menus don't need to be edited via the delegate since they are built from scratch anyway.

For the `buildMenuWithBuilder` implementation in your app delegate, you will likely want to ignore any builders that isn't for the `mainSystem` (which will include context menus). To do that, check the system property of the builder and return if it's not the right type.

Swift:

```swift
func buildMenu(with builder: UIMenuBuilder) {
    // return if not the main system menu
    guard builder.system == UIMenuSystem.mainSystem else {
        return
    }
    
    // menu building code...
    builder.removeMenu(for: UIMenu.Identifier.file)
}
```

Objective C

```objectivec
- (void)buildMenuWithBuilder:(id<UIMenuBuilder>)builder {
    
    // return if not the main system menu
    if ([builder system] != [UIMenuSystem mainSystem]) {
        return;
    }
 
    // menu building code...
    [builder removeMenuForIdentifier:UIMenuFile];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at this when I have time. For now the catalyst development is on hold as the iPad version gets hardened.